# How do I sequence a list of tuples?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to sequence a list of `(Int, Int)` tuples into a list of int lists `[[Int]]`

Why? I've found many use cases for this. Basically given a list like so:

```
[(1,5), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (6,7), (7,8)]
```

I want to return a list:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
pieces :: [(Int, Int)]
pieces = [(1,5), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (6,7), (7,8)]

linkStep :: [[Int]] -> (Int, Int) -> [[Int]]
linkStep (x:xs) (a, b)
    | elem a x = (b : x) : xs
    | elem b x = (a : x) : xs
    | otherwise = (a : b : x) : xs

-- Now I fold the linkStep function over the list
links :: [(Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
links list = foldl linkStep [[]] list
```

However when I call `links` with `pieces` I get

```
links pieces
--[[8,6,7,5,4,2,3,1,5]]
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. The `linkStep` function is supposed to concatenate a tuple element that is in the resulting list to the target list in the result. If the tuple element is not yet in the resulting list a new list with the tuple element is added. But its not working... Please help!

Comment: The exmple return value `[1,2,3,4,5]` doesn't have type `[[Int]]`.  It is not clear to me what you want the return value to be.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5]` is a list of `Int`, not a list of list of `Int`. It's not clear what `linkStep` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Oh sorry, typo. I've updated the example.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "sequence", or what `linkStep` is supposed to do. Assuming `links` is correct, perhaps you could show a few examples of how `linkStep` is supposed to operate?

Comment: Why should the result be `[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8]]` and not e.g. `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]` or `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8]]` or even `[[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7],[8]]` ? What is the general criterion?

Comment: The tuples (1,5) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5) have overlapping elements. (6,7) (7,8) do not (with 1-5)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues that I see:

1. In `linkStep`, you only ever check if your tuple elements are members of the first inner list. From your example, it looks as if you're going to need to check all the lists, not just the first one.
2. In the cases of `linkStep`, you always add `a`, `b`, or both `a` and `b` to the first inner list. Thus all elements will eventually end up in the first list. Maybe you meant to create a new list here instead? But it might also be a good place to consider other lists than the first.

Hopefully this will help you to make progress.